# Правильная реализация обработки ошибок Retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit, request

Возник довольно интересный вопрос - правильно ли реализована мной обработка ошибок в моем клиент-серверном приложении. Вот как реализовано в моем синглтоне для обращения к интерфейсу:

```
fun apiService(): APIService {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val disp = Dispatcher()
        disp.maxRequests = 1


        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .dispatcher(disp)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()

        client.dispatcher.cancelAll()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        return retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
    }
```

и теперь как реализовано в запросе обработка ошибок:

```
fun archiveNote(id: Int?, context: Context) {
        apiService().archiveNote("Bearer " + context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", ""), id).enqueue(object : Callback<NoteAction> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<NoteAction>, response: Response<NoteAction>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                } else {
                    if (response.code() == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        try {
                            val jObjError = JSONObject(Objects.requireNonNull<ResponseBody>(response.errorBody()).string())
                            error["message"] = jObjError.getString("message")
                            error["request_no"] = "20"
                            workingWithErrors(error, context)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NoteAction>, t: Throwable) {

            }

        })
    }
```

и вот бывают ситуации когда запрос на обновление токена идет, то может быть послано 5 например запросов для обновление токена, а это неправильно. Поэтому задался вопросом правильно ли то что я обрабатываю результат запроса в теле метода, а именно:

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {

} else {

}
```

Может есть какие-то практики которые делают процесс обработки ошибок более совершенным и правильным. Приведенный выше вариант реализации мне кажется является наиболее встречаемым и популярным.

вот как я отлавливаю момент протухания токена:

```
sp.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60
```

то есть если это условие выполняется то шлем запрос на обновление токена, либо шлем запрос какой нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну понятия правильно тут наверное нет. Все зависит от того как и где вы хотите обрабатывать ошибки.

Есть несколько вариантов обработки ошибок. 
1. Обрабатывать их непосредственно в месте возникновения. Т.е. как только вы ее получили в вашем классе, отвечающим, за запросы в сеть там же и обработали. В таком случае вы будете точно знать где возникла ошибка. Если, к примеру, вы хотите просто залогировать ошибку или выполнить действия и никак не оповещать пользователя, это хорошее решение.
2. Вариант пробрасывать эту ошибку в сущности которые непосредственно взаимодействуют с пользователем. В таком случае вам будет труднее отследить место возникновения этой ошибки, но вы сможете обработать ее на уровне UI (например показать пользователю уведомление или какой-то другой экран). Тут есть пару походов.

Первый, это просто пробросить ее по стеку вызовов вверх. И там просто отреагировать.
  Второй, который мне нравится больше - обернуть ошибку в какое-то состояние и вернуть это состояние вызывающему объекту.

Вот тут вы можете просмотреть мою реализацию второго подхода

https://github.com/industradamus/TheMovie/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/wispapp/themovie/core/model/network/RemoteProvider.kt

Comment: обновил немного вопрос, я использую условие для проверки протухлости